# Projecting coordinates into different EPSGs gives inconsistencies

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, epsg

I am using 3 EPSGs: 4326 (WGS84), 3857 (Mercator) and 3035 (EU Copernicus dataset).

I am trying to easily convert coordinates from one system to any other. To do so, I wrote a `Coordinate` class with the following method, which serves to take the point's coordinates `self.x` and `self.y` given in `self.epsg` and project them into `new_epsg`:

```
   # Project point into given EPSG system
   def project(self, new_epsg):
      # Create transform from src epsg to dst epsg
      src = osr.SpatialReference()
      src.ImportFromEPSG(self.epsg)

      dst = osr.SpatialReference()
      dst.ImportFromEPSG(new_epsg)

      transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(src, dst)

      # Create and project point
      wkt = 'POINT ({} {})'.format(self.x, self.y)
      point = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)
      point.Transform(transform)

      self.epsg = new_epsg
      self.x = point.GetX()
      self.y = point.GetY()

      return self
```

However, when converting from an epsg to another the coordinates are always wrong.

**Testing I've done:**

I've tried a combination of two things:

- flipping the coordinates in input i.e. `wkt = 'POINT ({} {})'.format(self.y, self.x)` instead of `self.x, self.y`
- flipping the coordinates in output i.e. `self.x = point.GetY()` `self.y = point.GetX()`

To test my code, I've used a single point in the 3 ESPGs using https://epsg.io/. The coordinates are (x, y):

- (1) EPSG 4326: (-31.22000, 39.443505) see here https://epsg.io/map#srs=4326&x=-31.22000&y=39.443505&z=12&layer=streets
- (2) EPSG 3857: (-3475394.537268, 4785400.320095) see here https://epsg.io/map#srs=3857&x=-3475394.537268&y=4785400.320095&z=12&layer=streets
- (3) EPSG 3035: (949571.84, 2769907.62) see here https://epsg.io/map#srs=3035&x=949571.84&y=2769907.62&z=12&layer=streets

Now here are the results:

- not flipping anything: *nothing works*
- flipping only input: *only (1) to (2) and (3) to (2) work*
- flipping only output: *only (2) to (1) and (2) to (3) work*
- flipping both: *only (1) to (3) and (3) to (1) work*

So overall by flipping coordinates around I can get all cases to work but this is very case specific and I would much rather have a general one-fits-all function.

More (runnable) code is available at https://pastebin.com/vzDkC3QM

I hope I didn't just miss something stupid.

Comment: In each case you need to consider the axis order of the crs - so in some you need to flip and in others you don't

Comment: Yes, like Ian states:  axis order may not be consistent between EPSG. See here https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html and here: https://proj.org/faq.html#why-is-the-axis-ordering-in-proj-not-consistent.

Answer (score 1):

https://gdal.org/tutorials/osr_api_tut.html#crs-and-axis-order

If you would like a simpler solution, when creating the spatial reference objects, make sure to do:

```py
crs.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)
```

Comment: To clarify - this behaviour is imposed by GDAL/OGR, and not PROJ because the former needs to express a projection in ESRI or (modified ESRI) WKT format, but a one-to-one between PROJ and WKT is not always possible. IMHO, this is an unfortunate addition.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Ian and GBG the issue was indeed with axes being inverted in some cases, but not all (here for 4326 and 3035).

I'll quote the links posted by GBG as they were very instructional:

- https://proj.org/faq.html#why-is-the-axis-ordering-in-proj-not-consistent
- https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html

Here's my updated code that takes into account inverted axes if that can help anyone: https://pastebin.com/8CFV62z8